# minecraft granite id

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am summoning items that don't die or get picked up for my command block shop and am doing granite and I know it's id is stone (`1`) but how do I do it in a command? My current command is:

```
/summon Item ~ ~2 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:stone:1,Count:1},Age:-32768,PickupDelay:32767}
```

Nothing summons and I know it is because of the id because I've done it with other blocks and they work. What do I put in for the id for granite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:1` is not part of granite's id, but rather its `Damage` value:

```
/summon Item ~ ~2 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:stone,Damage:1,Count:1},Age:-32768,PickupDelay:32767}
```

Comment: i also would like to know how when i am doing sel,ling items in my shop i want it to test for them and it wont sell them if they have more than the specified amount so how do i test for greater than an amount

Comment: nevermind that wasnt what was wrong i fixed it